# How to insert data in array of type string?

Tags: asp.net

I am  selecting data from database and in while loop, i want it store all data in one variable. How to do that? 
The variable selectAnswer is string array type .

I used this code but this give error. Modify this code.

```
string selectAnswer[] = new string[];
while (rdr.Read())
{
    selectAnswer[] = rdr[0].ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite confusing. 
You want to store the data into a single variable or into a single string?
If that's the case why not use a StringBuilder instead.

```
StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    answer.AppendLine(rdr[0].ToString());
}
```

But I'm still not sure if I undestood correctly.

Other option is using a list:

```
IList<string> answer = new List<string>();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    answer.Add(rdr[0].ToString());
}
answer.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [generic List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead, it has several [advantages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172194.aspx):

```
List<String> selectAnswer = new List<String>(); 
while (rdr.Read())
{
    selectAnswer.Add(rdr[0].ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a single string to the whole array instead of a single string per array item.

You can use a `List<string>` instead of an array of strings and simply add items to it:

```
IList<string> selectAnswer = new List<string>();
while (rdr.Read())
{
    selectAnswer.Add(rdr[0].ToString());
}
```

For this to work with an array, you will first need to declare the array variable with the number of items in the data reader and have a counter for which index you are inserting on.